# Is this C++ ref example buggy?

Tags: c++

I was checking `aligned_storage` in [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), but I think its example is buggy. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
 
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for N T's
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
    std::size_t m_size = 0;
 
public:
    // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
 
        // construct value in memory of aligned storage
        // using inplace operator new
        new(&data[m_size]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
    }
 
    // Access an object in aligned storage
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const 
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]);
    }
 
    // Delete objects from aligned storage
    ~static_vector() 
    {
        for(std::size_t pos = 0; pos < m_size; ++pos) {
            // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[pos])->~T();
        }
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    static_vector<std::string, 10> v1;
    v1.emplace_back(5, '*');
    v1.emplace_back(10, '*');
    std::cout << v1[0] << '\n' << v1[1] << '\n';
}
```

Here we want to create a static vector that uses [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). The problem is that `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type` type is POD, not `T`. so we need to cast it before using. I think code should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
 
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for N T's
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
    T* data_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(data);

    std::size_t m_size = 0;
 
public:
    // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
 
        // construct value in memory of aligned storage
        // using inplace operator new
        new(&data_ptr[m_size]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
    }
 
    // Access an object in aligned storage
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const 
    {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data_ptr[pos]);
    }
 
    // Delete objects from aligned storage
    ~static_vector() 
    {
        for(std::size_t pos = 0; pos < m_size; ++pos) {
            // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data_ptr[pos])->~T();
        }
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    static_vector<std::string, 10> v1;
    v1.emplace_back(5, '*');
    v1.emplace_back(10, '*');
    std::cout << v1[0] << '\n' << v1[1] << '\n';
}
```

Am I right? Although I don't know why original code works in clang.

**Update:**

Let me be more specific. By standard, `aligned_storage` type is POD not `T`. so its implementation can be as following:

```
template<std::size_t Len, std::size_t Align /* default alignment not implemented */>
struct aligned_storage {
    struct type {
        alignas(Align) unsigned char data[Len];
    };
};
```

Now if you access this with `data[pos]`, address will be increased based on `unsigned char` size=1, not `sizeof(T)` isn't it?

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and all warnings enabled: `g++ -Wall -Wextra` ?

Comment: Why do you think your variant is better? Their code looks ok to me, but I smell a minor UB in yours, because `data` is not an array of `T`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat problem is that `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type` type is not `T` and is POD.  so `data[m_size]` will be overlap for different objects if object size is bigger than 1. you need to cast it before using it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah my code? or cppref?

Comment: `&a[i]` returns the address of i-th array element. Always, regardless of the element type. Remember that `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`, and when adding an integer to a pointer, the integer is multiplied by `sizeof` of the pointed type.

Comment: "will be overlap for different objects if object size is bigger than 1." This sentence doesn't parse.

Comment: They both look identical. Have you tried simply printing the address generated by both methods to see if you get different results? Note: `X[Y]` is simply syntactic sugar for `*(X + Y)` and `&*Exp` is simply `Exp`. => `&data[m_size]` is the same as `&*(data + m_size)` is the same as `(data + m_size)` So as long as `data` is a pointer to an object of the size size as `T` the expressions are identical.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat updated my post. The problem is that in `aligned_storage` data is allocated in for example `unsigned char` not type `T`. so when you are using `&a[i]` it access members assuming each member size is 1 (pointer was `unsigned char`) not `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: The example is correct. `data` contains aligned elements, this `&data[i]` is a proper location for the i-th element. When you cast `data` to `T*`, you violate the alignment and cause UB.

Comment: @S.M. `alignas(Align) unsigned char data[Len];` means each element is aligned? or the whole array is aligned?

Comment: `sizeof(char[Len])` is not 1. More precise `sizeof(char[sizeof(T)])` is `sizeof(T)`, not 1.

Comment: "_when you are using &a[i] it access members assuming each member size is 1_" - `data` is an array of `struct type { alignas(Align) unsigned char data[Len]; };`.

Comment: @Afshin No. The size of the object is the size of `aligned_storage`. So it increments y the size of `data[Len]` (ie. the whole array is one item).

Comment: See the example: https://ideone.com/7NxxKV
`sizeof(data[0]) = 32`, `sizeof(T) = 32`. Not 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
```

You seem to think that `&data[i]` will return the address of i-th byte in this array, while in reality it will return the address of `i * sizeof(std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>)`th byte, which is the same as `i * sizeof(T)`th byte. [Example.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aTnsKPqdT)

> OP: The problem is that in `aligned_storage` data is allocated in for example `unsigned char` not type `T`. so when you are using `&a[i]` it access members assuming each member size is `1` (pointer was `unsigned char`) not `sizeof(T)`.

This is not how it works. It doesn't matter what type `aligned_storage` uses under the hood, `unsigned char[N]` or something else.

For brevity, let's use `using A = std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;`.

The array `data` has type `A[N]`. When you apply operator `[]` to it, it decays to a pointer of type `A *`.

`data[i]` is equivalent to `*(data + i)`. When adding an integer to a pointer, the integer is multiplied by `sizeof` of the pointed type. The pointed type is `A`, so `sizeof(A)` is used (which is equal to `sizeof(T)`).

Comment: That the sizeof of aligned_storage<>::type and sizeof(T) are the same doesn't seem to be promised. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1413r2.pdf

Comment: @JeffGarrett Formally yes, but in practice they should be equal.